# Basic meet the team page

Tags: css, html, canvas

How can I make the "About" box to move down, to be even with the "Email" box.
I tried with height="something" but it moves up not down, so it messes my page.

So basically i want the "About" box to be same size as boxes "Photo,Email,Whatsapp etc." in height.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
  <canvas id="Photo" width="200" height="230" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
  </canvas>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("Photo");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Photo Here",20,110);
  </script>
  <canvas id="About" width="500" height="230" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
  </canvas><br>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("About");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("About Page",150,110);
  </script>
  <canvas id="Real_Name" width="200" height="30" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
  </canvas>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("Real_Name");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "15px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Real Name",60,20);
  </script><br>
  <canvas id="Role" width="200" height="30" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
  </canvas>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("Role");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "15px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Role",81,20);
  </script><br>
  <canvas id="WhatsApp" width="200" height="30" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
  </canvas><br>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("WhatsApp");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "15px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("WhatsApp",60,20);
  </script>
  <canvas id="Email" width="200" height="30" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
  </canvas>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("Email");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = "15px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Email",77,20);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest doing a basic html / css tutorial as making simple boxes with text using canvases is not very efficient in performance for rendering and if you don't know a simple thing like how to place boxes beside each other, you would really benefit from a bit of knowledge

Comment: What tutorial do you recommend? @Pete

Comment: Do a search, there are hundreds of good ones - it's up to you and what you find easy to use

Answer (score 0):

The reason the sizes didn't match is that you missed off a **BR** tag after /canvas for "About" - so it should be:

```
   <canvas id="About" width="200" height="30" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
   Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
   </canvas> <br>
   <script>
```

Then you will have them all in a row.

You also need to close your header and HTML tags correctly, so at the bottom

```
 </body>
</head>
</html>
```

If you want to put all of that content in your header of course.

Here is the modified code, in full :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<canvas id="Photo" width="200" height="230" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("Photo");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Photo Here",20,110);
</script><br>
<canvas id="About" width="200" height="230" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas><br>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("About");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("About Page",150,110);
</script><br>
<canvas id="Real_Name" width="200" height="30" style="border:1px solid #000000;"><br>
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<script>    var canvas = document.getElementById("Real_Name");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "15px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Real Name",60,20);
</script><br>
<canvas id="Role" width="200" height="30" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("Role");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "15px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Role",81,20);
</script><br>
<canvas id="WhatsApp" width="200" height="30" style="border:1px solid #000000;">    
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas><br>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("WhatsApp");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "15px Arial";
ctx.fillText("WhatsApp",60,20);
</script>
<canvas id="Email" width="200" height="30" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("Email");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "15px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Email",77,20);
</script>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: It's the same thing.

Comment: If you have changed the width to all the same values for each canvas entry, then it will display correctly, although you could set a style using CSS to save you having to change the width five times over.

Comment: Hard to explain but, i want the "About" box to be same size as boxes "Photo,Email,Whatsapp etc." in height. I don't know how to explain.

Comment: Ok, you just need to change height to all of the same values, so: <canvas id="About" width="200" height="30" style="border:1px solid #000000;"> make sure all of the height="30" are all the same value if you want them to be 30px wide

Comment: That's not what i'm trying to do. I'm trying to move the bottom bar of the box named "About" down. So it can be evenly with the bottom line of the box named "Email".

Comment: Ok, you really need to apply CSS styles, because they define padding, border size and most importantly, with bootstrap, you can implement a responsive design, so the content resizes according to the screen size and resolution of the user automatically.  Plus you can learn how to easily implement content boxes, rather than loads of canvas', which can be very intensive on the server load. If you go to [link]https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/  - you will pick it up in 30 mins and save all of this botching to make it display correctly.